# Flutter Testing api Using MockClient

Tags: flutter, dart, testing

Im trying to test a function using MockClient in in flutter the function should return Json this the code that I write for testing

```
    final newsApi = NewsApiProvider();
    newsApi.client = MockClient((request) async {
      return Response(json.encode({"id": 123}), 200);
    });
    final item = await newsApi.fetchItem(123);
    expect(item.id, 123);
  });
```

and this is the error I got
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6WRd.png

this is the model class look like

```
class ItemModel {
  final int id;
  final bool deleted;
  final String type;
  final String by;
  final int time;
  final String text;
  final bool dead;
  final int parent;
  final List<dynamic> kids;
  final String url;
  final int score;
  final String title;
  final int descendants;

  ItemModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : id = json['id'],
        deleted = json['deleted'],
        type = json['type'],
        by = json['by'],
        time = json['time'],
        text = json['text'],
        dead = json['dead'],
        parent = json['parent'],
        kids = json['kids'],
        url = json['url'],
        score = json['score'],
        title = json['title'],
        descendants = json['descendants'];
}
```

and this the function I need to test

```
    fetchItem(int id) async {
        final res = await client.get(Uri.parse("$_root_url/item/$id.json?"));
        final res_json = json.decode(res.body);
        return ItemModel.fromJson(res_json);
      }
```

I can't understand why this happening do I need to write the whole Json response in order to test if thats the case why need to use mock client